# What does the various brackets mean on the indicator margin of Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

[image: various brackets on the indicator margin of Visual Studio 2019]

What does those brackets mean? They changes with selection change.
Can't find an answer after googling for half an hour... :(

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is a rendering bug. It looks like a vertical slice of code `<` `>` `_[]` `,`. Probably the buffer wasn't redrawn, and because the font is different I think this is  from a different window.

Comment: @beothunder The angle brackets seem to change in accordance with selection in the editor. Does those signs show on your computer?

Comment: I have never seen anything like this (neither in my editor nor in someone elses), except on windows XP where redrawing bugs did this all the time, hence my comment. Also the clipping of those symbols really makes it seem like a bug than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These characters are from your VsVim: https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/blob/master/Src/VimCore/CoreTypes.fs#L487. I just asked this question and a commenter pointed my to check my Extensions, so I searched their repo and found the only reference to them (in the source).

Other good links are:

- http://glyphlist.azurewebsites.net/knownmonikers/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/margin-indicators